# Converting Bitmap into a valid Uri

Tags: java, android, bitmap

I am developing an android app where user is selecting the image either from gallery or capture from camera. When user get the image from gallery i get the image uri then i pass this uri to other activity in string form. then in next activity i convert that string into uri and then uri into bitmap and set the image bitmap in imageview. Now when i capture the image from camera i get the image bitmap.
Now i want to convert this bitmap into valid uri and pass to next activity

```
    if(requestCode==GET_FROM_GALLERY && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            System.out.println("URLLL "+selectedImage);
            Log.v("PhotoActivity", "Captured image");

            //Create intent
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, FlagDisplayActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("URI", selectedImage.toString());
            //Start Flag Display activity
            startActivity(intent);
            Log.v("PHOTO ACTIVITY", " uri: " + selectedImage);
        }
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
        {

            Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");

            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, FlagDisplayActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("URI", photo);
            //Start Flag Display activity
            startActivity(intent);

}
```

This is how i get the uri in next activity

```
  String imageUriString=getIntent().getStringExtra("URI");
        final Uri selectedImage=Uri.parse(imageUriString);
```

and then convert the uri into bitmap like this

```
Bitmap bitmap = null;
    try {
        bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(),
                selectedImage);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        bitmap=StringToBitMap(imageUriString);
    }
```

My main goal is to convert the bitmap into uri

Comment: Uri.fromFile(f); ???

Comment: You could save the Bitmap in the local Cache, get the URI and delete the cached file in the other activity. If the File isn't on your device saved, you won't get an URI

Comment: `Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");` That will give you only a thumbnail of your image. Is that what you want?

Comment: `My main goal is to convert the bitmap into uri `. One cannot convert a bitmap to an uri to begin with. But you could save the bitmal as .jpg or .png to file and then obtain an uri of the file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You write your Bitmap into the local Cache of the Application and retrieve it from there.

```
Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");// Get the Bitmap


  val file = File(context.cacheDir,"CUSTOM NAME") //Get Access to a local file. 
  file.delete() // Delete the File, just in Case, that there was still another File
  file.createNewFile() 
  val fileOutputStream = file.outputStream()
  val byteArrayOutputStream = ByteArrayOutputStream()
  photo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,100,byteArrayOutputStream)
  val bytearray = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray()
  fileOutputStream.write(bytearray)
  fileOutputStream.flush()
  fileOutputStream.close()
  byteArrayOutputStream.close()

  val URI = file.toURI()
```

Now you can send the URI to another Activity as a String and retrieve the URI from the String and get the Bitmap from the URI.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, FlagDisplayActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("URI", URI.toString());
        //Start Flag Display activity
        startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: let me try it ..wait

Comment: i need for java

Comment: Android Studio for example got a kotlin to Java converter

Comment: what is value of selectedimage in first line?

Comment: That is your Code, not mine

Comment: To Convert this to Java, the most simple method is, to replace any val or var with the associated Class

Comment: what is context.cacheDir in second line?

Comment: that is the context of your activity. Cachedir get's the Cachedir as a File, the 2nd Parameter is the Name of the File

Comment: cacheDir is unknown

Comment: This is kotlin smartcode, just look for getcachedir

Comment: In Kotlin you can replace getX with simple X for get

Comment: too much smart code because a lot of classes are unknown

Comment: bmap.compress ...what is bmap here?

Comment: file.outputstream() is also unknown

Comment: dont get angry i m just asking for help

Answer (score 1):

Provide the path of image it will provide you image uri

```
Uri selectedImageURI = data.getData();
File imageFile = new File(getRealPathFromURI(selectedImageURI));
Uri yourUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
```

Use the following function so you will get image

```
private String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentURI) {
    String result;
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(contentURI, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor == null) { // Source is Dropbox or other similar local file path
        result = contentURI.getPath();
    } else { 
        cursor.moveToFirst(); 
        int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA); 
        result = cursor.getString(idx);
        cursor.close();
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: I think u didn't read the question i m asking how to convert the bitmap into uri

Comment: it's the same answer for you. Sir just provide file path it will provide you uri

Comment: i have only image bitmap and that image is at runtime..how can i provide its path?

Comment: as you can see `data.getData();` which is image data just pass the data to getPath.

Comment: which i should copy? u wrote "or" between them

Comment: both are same function you can use 2nd function if you want information about that i can help you

Comment: let me try don't get offline

Comment: ImageFilePath  is unknow

Comment: @UmarGhaffar use second one it will help you

Comment: in second one, getpath is unknown

Comment: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1888, result=-1, data=Intent { act=inline-data (has extras) }} to activity {com.hexaloop.faceapp/com.hexaloop.faceapp.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: uri

Comment: your uri is null

Comment: `Uri selectedImageURI = data.getData();` You are on the wrong way. You clearly can see in the original post that it does not give an uri but a bitmap. `Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");`. There is no uri then. Your post is completely wrong and was very confusing for OP.

Answer (score -3):

Try this:

```
bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), uri);
imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Comment: he is looking for uri to uri